# Store Time series data in SQL Server, and pull the data dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I am trying to design a relation based database, but at the same time store time series data.

For example, I have one table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fund](
[FundID] [int] NOT NULL,
[FundName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FundCurrency] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Fund] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

I have another table to store the data, except the first column's name 'Dates', all the others are f+fundID, e.g. f1001.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FundData](
[Dates] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[f1001] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FundData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

I don't know whether this naive way is efficient or not. Since the data it will handle will be not much. Daily quote, max 10 year's daily data, and max 500 columns.

But the real problem I am facing, is how to create a UDF to return a series of data with dates, with input FundID and BeginDate and EndDate. Or how to create a Stored Procedure to return one single quote, given FundID and Date.

Since UDF don't accept dynamic column name, I really don't know how I can achieve this. Either by redesign how to store the data, or by some smart way of making UDF.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add FundId as a foreign Key to FundData, add Begin and End date for each record (assuming I understand the problem correctly)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FundData](
[Dates] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[FundId] int NOT NULL,
[Value] [float] NULL,
[BeginDate] [datetime],
[EndDate] [datetime],
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FundData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 CONSTRAINT [FK_FundData_Fund] FOREIGN KEY FundId REFERENCES Fund(FundId)
)
```

you can then do the following where `@FundId, @BeginDate` and `@EndDate` are all T-SQL variables or stored procedure parameters

```
SELECT Value
FROM FundData
WHERE FundID = @FundId
AND BeginDate >= @BeginDate
AND EndDate <= @EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you mean I should store the time series data like this:     ID1001 2013-01-01 32.31; ID1001 2013-01-02 32.87;ID1001 2013-01-03 34.97; ID1002 2013-01-01 79.26; ID1002 2013-01-02 81.97; ID1003 2013-01-03 82.18;

Comment: So you mean, instead of trying store the data in a matrix structure, I should store the data in a flat structure, with ID dates and value for each row? Good idea, actually. Thank you very much!